# Comparing one point with the next in a time series of data in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have a column called signal with values stored for every minute of recording.
I want to compare the first value with the second and if the difference is over 4, then it should output a 1, if under 4, then a 0. 
I then want to do this between the second and third, third and fourth, fourth and fifth, and so on.

Comment: Try `diff(signal)>4`.

Comment: [Check this for information on how to provide a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```
df$newcolumn <- ifelse(diff(df$signal)>4, 1, 0)
```